# mysql fulltext returning odd values

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, ranking

I am trying to create a search tool that takes a text field that can contain some or all of a title, one or more author names in any order, and terms in the abstract and tries to find the most likely publication that the user is looking for.  But the rankings being returned are off.

Even if the text entered is word for word the beginning of the title, if I order by the MATCH results the ideal result is no where near the top of the results.

Any thoughts on a better solution for creating an accurate ranking of results?

*SQL*

```
SELECT `title`, (MATCH (`title`) AGAINST ("Data Trends #55")) AS `rank_title`
FROM `tblPublications`
HAVING (`rank_title`) > 1
  ORDER BY `rank_title`  DESC
```

*data*

```
title   rank_title 
Data Trends #140: The Role of Data Collection and Evaluation in Supporting Systems Change.  3.2141819000244
Data Trends #70: From Incarceration to Community.   2.7096807956696
Data Trends #12: Under Court Order. 2.7096807956696
Data Trends #78: Inclusion in Schools.  2.7096807956696
Data Trends #43: Paraprofessionals in Educational Settings. 2.6802139282227
Data Trends #35: Respite Care and Outcome.  2.6802139282227
Data Trends #08: Developments in Systems of Care.   2.6802139282227
Data Trends #07: Development of an Outcome Evaluation.  2.6802139282227
Data Trends #03: Families as Researchers and Evaluators.    2.6802139282227
Data Trends #02: Caregiver Enrichment and Stress.   2.6802139282227
Data Trends #97: The Relationships Between Poverty and Psychopathology. 2.6802139282227
Data Trends #111: Stigma and Mental Illness.    2.6802139282227
Data Trends #115: Building on Caregiver Strengths.  2.6802139282227
Data Trends #142: Defining the Wraparound Process.  2.6802139282227
Data Trends #71: Family Interventions in Serious Mental Illness.    2.6513810157776
Data Trends #63: Implementing IDEA '97 Disciplinary Provisions. 2.6513810157776
Data Trends #57: Using the Parents as Partners Principle with SED Children. 2.6513810157776
Data Trends #49: Cultural Competence: Caregiver Perspectives.   2.6513810157776
Data Trends #47: Service Use & Intensive Family Preservation.   2.6513810157776
Data Trends #44: Mood Disorders: Treatment Patterns in an HMO.  2.6513810157776
Data Trends #38: Adolescent Drug Treatment and Outcome. 2.6513810157776
Data Trends #34: Family-Centered Early Intervention.    2.6513810157776
Data Trends #31: Juvenile Justice and Mental Health.    2.6513810157776
Data Trends #25: Children's Mental Health in the Media. 2.6513810157776
Data Trends #18: Attribution in Children's Mental Health.   2.6513810157776
Data Trends #15:  Mechanisms of Change in Multisystemic Therapy.    2.6513810157776
Data Trends #10: Toxic Threats to Child Development.    2.6513810157776
Data Trends #73: Having a Brother with Emotional and/or Behavioral Challenges.  2.6513810157776
Data Trends #74: Research and Advocacy for Policy Change.   2.6513810157776
Data Trends #79: Family Perspectives on Having a Child with a Disability.   2.6513810157776
Data Trends #81: Explaining the Gap Between Mental Health Need and Service Use. 2.6513810157776
Data Trends #91: The Implications of Incarceration for Families and Children.   2.6513810157776
Data Trends #84: Working Relationships across Diverse Communities.  2.6513810157776
Data Trends #86: Community Interventions and Effective Prevention.  2.6513810157776
Data Trends #95: Maternal Employment when Children Have Disabilities.   2.6513810157776
Data Trends #99: Clinicians and How They Use and View Outcome Measurement.  2.6513810157776
Data Trends #108: Practice and Process in Wraparound Teamwork.  2.6513810157776
Data Trends #122: Outcomes for Youth Following Psychiatric Emergencies. 2.6513810157776
Data Trends #133: Evaluating treatment for homeless adolescents 2.6513810157776
Data Trends #156: Assessing the Sustainability of Systems of Care.  2.6513810157776
Data Trends #159: Out-of-Home Placements Within Systems of Care 2.6513810157776
Data Trends #64: Impact of Poverty on Family Quality of Life.   2.6231617927551
Data Trends #54: Mental Health Referral in Juvenile Justice.    2.6231617927551
Data Trends #53: Clinical Profiles of Youth in a System of Care.    2.6231617927551
Data Trends #45: Mood Disorders: Accuracy of Screening Instruments. 2.6231617927551
Data Trends #39: Violence: Emotional & Behavioral Impact & Prevention.  2.6231617927551
Data Trends #37: Racial Differences in Service Placement Patterns.  2.6231617927551
Data Trends #28: Suicidal Ideation, Depression, and Help-Seeking Among Adolescents. 2.6231617927551
Data Trends #26: Foster Care: Importance of Training and Support.   2.6231617927551
Data Trends #24: Needs Assessment and Service Coordination in an Inner City Neighborhood.   2.6231617927551
Data Trends #19: Custody Relinquishment: Impact of Research on Policy.  2.6231617927551
Data Trends #17: Offering Technical Assistance to Native Families.  2.6231617927551
Data Trends #13: Child Abuse and Neglect in Indian Country. 2.6231617927551
Data Trends #05: Consumer Satisfaction with Mental Health Services. 2.6231617927551
Data Trends #76: Community-Based Interventions for Affective Disorders. 2.6231617927551
Data Trends #77: Adolescent Help-Seeking Behavior: Role of the Internet.    2.6231617927551
Data Trends #80: Impact of Support on Adolescent Mental Health. 2.6231617927551
Data Trends #85: Culture-Centered Practice in Services for Children.    2.6231617927551
Data Trends #90: Exposure to Violence, Stress, Protective Factors, and Well-being.  2.6231617927551
Data Trends #92: Depictions of Mental Illness in Children's Media.  2.6231617927551
Data Trends #105: Collective socialization and child conduct problems.  2.6231617927551
Data Trends #116: Domestic Violence and Children's Mental Health.   2.6231617927551
Data Trends #121: Quality and Individualization in Wraparound Team Planning.    2.6231617927551
Data Trends #124: The Stigmatization of Mental Illness in Children and Families.    2.6231617927551
Data Trends #125: Neighborhood Residence and the Problems of School-Age Children.   2.6231617927551
Data Trends #149: What Constitutes Youth Involvement in Systems of Care?    2.6231617927551
Data Trends #151: Are Brothers and Sisters a Good Source of Support?    2.6231617927551
Data Trends #150: Understanding ADHD: Examining Racial Differences. 2.6231617927551
Data Trends #152: Family Participation in Action: Are Families Actually Involved?   2.6231617927551
Data Trends #158: Children's Perspectives of Their Mental Health Services.  2.6231617927551
Data Trends #160: Peer Stigmatization of Childhood Depression and ADHD  2.6231617927551
Data Trends #68: Prevalence of Psychiatric Disorders in Youth in Juvenile Detention.    2.5955367088318
Data Trends #59: Factors Associated with Response Inconsistency in Structured Diagnostic Interviews.    2.5955367088318
Data Trends #55: Mental Health Screening Instruments for use in Juvenile Justice.   2.5955367088318
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default minimum length for words is four as [described here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html).  Information about changing that is described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html).

Therefore search `Data Trends #55` is probably equivalent to `Data Trends`.  The verify first row in the shown result set has the word `Data` a second time in the title, which probably explains why it ranks the highest.

Comment: Even when I search for Data Trends #158 the desired result is at least 2 pages down.

Comment: Hmmm.  It could be that the `#` character is ignored.  I had looked for information on that but could not find if there were certain characters that are ignored/dropped by default.  If that is the case, then it would still be, effectively, a 3 letter word.